# How to define Start Url for all users in a role in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

I have  list of users in Sitecore tied to Active Directory. I would like to associate a default Start Url in the User Profile for particular Roles instead of setting them manually per user. I am unable to find a configuration in the Security Tools section of the Desktop nor in the configuration files. Is it possible to accomplish this? If so, how?

Comment: Do you mean a default root node in the Sitecore tree for those users?

Comment: @MartinDavies In the User Manager -> Under a specific user's "Profile" tab, inside the "User Profile" fieldset, the value that will be entered into the field named: "URL" as the Start Url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to create a custom profile it seems and assign a default value specifically for a text field named "StartUrl":

http://digital-learnings.blogspot.com/2015/02/customising-experience-for-sitecore-ad.html#.VXcH3UadqW4